# Jest won't clear cache

Tags: typescript, testing, jestjs, ts-jest

Jest is running old, outdated, commented out piece of code even after clearing it's cache.

It's almost like it's stuck in the past and i've ran the `jest --clearCache` command but this doesn't seem to solve this issue. if i comment out a test block, our even delete the test file, the test still runs. which is super super weird.

This is what my script looks like:

```
 "test": "jest  --detectOpenHandles --watchAll --forceExit",
```

Comment: Is there a way to access this folder to manually delete the file please? can't seem to find it

Answer (score 1):

It appears you might have jest installed globally *and* locally (in the project). So when you run `jest --clearCache` you are running it on the global installation of jest but in a `package.json` script it will call the jest local to the project. This means you have two caches (one gloabal and one local) and are simply trying to delete the wrong one.

In order to delete the projects cache you need to run:

```
npm run jest --clearCache
// or if using yarn
yarn jest --clearCache
```

also, (to address your comment) you can check where the cache directory is with:

```
jest --showConfig | grep cacheDir
// or in the project
npm run jest --showConfig | grep cacheDir
```

then delete the folder it returns.

Comment: I'm very sure you'd be surprised if i tell you that i've done all of these and yet it's still running outdated code.

Comment: what does `npm run jest --showConfig | grep cacheDir` return?

Comment: "cacheDirectory": "/private/var/folders/cl/6q9z20rj6jz8rwh_z0gl2mrw0000gn/T/jest_dx".

Comment: have you tried deleting that folder?

Comment: i did rm -rf cacheDirectory. this should delete it right?

Comment: you should pass the folder name `/private/var/folders/cl/6q9z20rj6jz8rwh_z0gl2mrw0000gn/T/jest_dx` not the property name `cacheDirectory`

Comment: so i did `rm -rf /private/var/folders/cl/6q9z20rj6jz8rwh_z0gl2mrw0000gn/T/jest_dx` and the problem still persists.

Comment: did you also try deleting the global cache directory returned from `jest --showConfig | grep cacheDir`. At this point i would uninstall the global installation of jest and just the one local to projects

Comment: Thing is, before now i didn't have a global installation of jest. just did couple of hours ago when i encountered this bug. i have now uninstalled it. This is super weird.

Comment: after uninstalling and trying to clear cache it is still doing this? i would restart terminal or even the computer. after that i am unsure what to do

Comment: Thank you for lending a hand. i think i found what the issue is

Comment: I think there might be something off with jest as well, though, as I am seeing similar behavior. Turns out, it was not actually running the commented code, but it WAS reporting the line number of commented code in the output. I could delete the commented lines and it would report the correct one, but adding them back, it output the same thing again. FWIW, I do NOT have a global installation of jest

Comment: Mhd - Any chance you could publish the solution.  Having the same issue, code is actually gone, cache folder deleted and yet I still receive "TypeError: mockGenerateBoleto.mockReturnValue is not a function", even though mockGenerateBoleto.mockReturnValue is gone.